# MySQL Join Queries task

Tags: mysql

I'm studying and stuck on a particular question regarding Join Queries.
The question is:
Use a join query to display the last name, job and education level of all employees who have at least the education level of the employee whose job description is 'Pres'.

Here's table description (The table is called Emp, so DESC Emp; brings up this):

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| empno     | char(6)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| firstname | varchar(12)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| midinit   | char(1)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| lastname  | varchar(15)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| workdept  | char(3)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| phoneno   | char(4)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| hiredate  | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| job       | char(10)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| edlevel   | int(2)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sex       | char(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| birthdate | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| salary    | decimal(8,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| bonus     | decimal(8,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| comm      | decimal(8,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

There are other tables too but I think this one is the only relevant one. There were 5 questions in total, but this question is the one that I can't seem to figure out. Please help!

Thank you.

EDIT: Just to clarify, 'job description' is called 'job' in the table. lastname and edlevel is self-explanatory.

EDIT2: Only 1 employee has 'Pres' as the job description.

Comment: I don't see "job description" into the table you showed. Do you mean "Job"?

Comment: @genespos Yes, sorry I didn't clarify. 'Job description' refers to 'job' in the table.

Comment: And there is only one employee with that job?

Comment: @AndrewBone Yes. Sorry for leaving that out.

Comment: well in that case, join it to it's self "select * from Emp join Emp as compare on (compare.job = "Pres") where Emp.edlevel >= compare.edlevel"

Comment: Do you have to use a join to get the pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your question , I assume that there is only one employee whose designation is 'Pres' and that detail is present in the 'job' column of the Emp table.

I think following query should work.

```
SELECT lastname,job,edlevel
FROM EMP
where edlevel >= (SELECT edlevel FROM EMP WHERE job='pres')
```

Let me know if this works!

Comment: It looks like they needed to use a join (for the question) so select * from Emp join Emp as compare on (compare.job = "Pres") where Emp.edlevel >= compare.edlevel

Comment: This works fine but @AndrewBone is right, I need to use a Join query. Going off what he's suggested I will post an answer that I have come up with that works well.

Comment: Well, it would be good to make it failproof (Sooner or later an error message will appear, like `subquery is returning more than one row`), so you should at least use an aggregate function in the subquery, `Min()` or `max()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @fancyPants and @AndrewBone I have come up with the answer that works and I think satisfies the question.

```
SELECT e.lastname, e.job, e.edlevel
FROM Emp e JOIN Emp compare ON compare.job='Pres'
WHERE e.edlevel >= compare.edlevel;
```

It's rather obvious once the answers there, but hindsight is 20/20. Took me quite a while to get the answer so thank you guys for helping.

If the answer is rather poorly written or if there is something wrong with it, please give me any suggestions on how it could be improved.